# Why would videojs HTML5 video not play sound in Firefox?

Tags: html, ogg, webm, video.js

I've converted an .mp4 video into .ogg and .webm formats (with ffmpeg) and used videojs to create the following web page that plays the video on all browsers (IE6-IE9, safari, chrome, opera, firefox):

http://tanguay.info/examples/testvideo

However, Firefox (12.0) does not always play the audio, depending on how the page is accessed:

Playing from **file://** with the **webm** source before ogg, Firefox plays **fine**:

```
<source src="videos/damconnect.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<source src="videos/damconnect.webm" type='video/webm'>
<source src="videos/damconnect.ogg" type='video/ogg'>
```

But playing from **file://** with the **ogg** source before webm, Firefox plays **without audio**:

And playing from **http://** with either **ogg** or **webm** first, Firefox plays **without audio**.

**How can I get Firefox to play via http:// with audio?**

---

### ADDENDUM:

Also: **Opera** will not play the video if **ogg** is listed first (just spins, doesn't start).

I notice that my tanguay.info server seems to be sending a text/plain header with the .webm video, how can I change that?

[image]

---

### ANSWER:

I added this .htaccess file to the directory where index.htm is, which fixed the problem:

```
AddType audio/ogg oga ogg
AddType video/ogg ogv
AddType video/webm webm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `text/plain` - edit your `mime.types` file (`~www/conf`) and add `webm/video webm`

Chances are you are having the same problem with `ogg/ogv`, add mime type `ogg/video ogg ogv`

Also ensure the audio codec is correct on conversion.

**EDIT**

[Ok, I see you added it to the `httpd.conf` - just read this](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-apache-config.html)

> 10.5.31. TypesConfig TypesConfig names the file which sets the default list of MIME type mappings (file name extensions to content types).
>   The default TypesConfig file is /etc/mime.types. Instead of editing
>   /etc/mime.types, the recommended way to add MIME type mappings is to
>   use the AddType directive.
>
> For more information about AddType, refer to [Section 10.5.54 AddType.](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-apache-config.html#S2-APACHE-ADDTYPE)

Although I can find any argument as to why...